# How to remove part of form for each change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

```
<select id="plage">
     <option>...</option>
</select>

<p id=changeplage">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#plage').change(function() {
        $("#changeplage").remove();

        var i;
        for(i=0;i<$(this).val();i++){
            $('form').append('From IP : ');
            $('<input name="fromip'+ (i+1) +'" type="text">').appendTo('form');

            $('form').append('To IP : ');
            $('<input name="toip'+ (i+1) +'" type="text">').appendTo('form');
        }

        $('<input type="submit" class="submit" name="send" value="Send">').appendTo('form');
    });
});
</script>

</p>
```

I just have inputs in a form and I want to remove them for each .change event in my form.
Without that, inputs add up in my display.
So I used jQuery.

.remove() doesn't work so when I click two times on select options, there is two inputs but I want to display just one, so replace the old input by the new.

How can I do that ? I tried with "replacewith", but no results.

Thanks for help (and sorry for my approximative english).

Comment: First fix the syntax errors

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you want to add fields onchange you want to add fields - when do you want to remove them?

Comment: I want to remove them when the user change the value on the select option.

Comment: Remove `what` ?

Comment: inputs in the "for" loop and submit input.

Comment: Hi Florian, do you mind giving us a working example at https://jsfiddle.net/ ? Thanks

Comment: instead of `$("#changeplage").remove();` try using `$("#changeplage").html('');`

Comment: My problem is resolved. I used empty() instead of remove() and the correct id to remove parts from the form. Thanks all.